# How to extract bracket from string into new columns

Tags: r, regex, split

I need to export information from a string into different columns.
More specifically the content of the brackets within the string;

Lets say I have a string

```
a <- "2xExp [K89; K96]; 1xExp [N-Term]; 2xNum [S87(100); S93(100)]"
```

What I am trying to output is a vector with the contents of the brackets, if there is a comma save them as separate bracketed strings, and remove parentheses.

e.g.

```
tmp <- function(a)
```

Result

```
tmp
"[K89]" , "[K96]", "[N-Term]", "[S87]", "[S93]"
```

My approach so far:

```
  pattern <- "(\\[.*?\\])"
  hits <- gregexpr(pattern, a)
  matches <- regmatches(a, hits)
  unlisted_matches <- unlist(matches)
```

Results

```
"[K89; K96]" "[N-Term]" "[S87(100); S93(100)]"
```

This does give me the brackets but still doesn't split the terms. And for any reason I am not able to efficiently separate the ";" terms.

Comment: It's going to be both technologically and mentally less expensive to do this in multiple steps rather than with one monster regex pattern. Your current pattern is a good first step. Nevertheless, I took it as a challenge and this was the best I could do (in a reasonable amount of time): https://regex101.com/r/LTtcJv/3

Comment: With PCRE `\G` operator (actually, it is an *anchor* like `^` or `$`), this is quite OK with a single regex like in my answer. If the format of the strings is consistent, the ruse of a single regex like that is IMHO justified well enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using the tidyverse :

```r
a <- "2xExp [K89; K96]; 1xExp [N-Term]; 2xNum [S87(100); S93(100)]"

library(tidyverse)
a %>% 
  # extract between square, brackets, not keeping brackets, and unlist
  str_extract_all("(?<=\\[).*?(?=\\])") %>% 
  unlist() %>%  
  # remove round brackets and content
  str_replace_all("\\(.*?\\)", "") %>%
  # split by ";" and unlist
  str_split("; ") %>%
  unlist() %>%
  # put the brackets back
  str_c("[",.,"]")
#> [1] "[K89]"    "[K96]"    "[N-Term]" "[S87]"    "[S93]"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
a <- "2xExp [K89; K96]; 1xExp [N-Term]; 2xNum [S87(100); S93(100)]"
pattern <- "(?:\\G(?!^)(?:\\([^()]*\\))?\\s*;\\s*|\\[)\\K[^][;()]+"
matches <- regmatches(a, gregexpr(pattern, a, perl=TRUE))
unlisted_matches <- paste0("[", unlist(matches),"]")
unlisted_matches
## => [1] "[K89]"    "[K96]"    "[N-Term]" "[S87]"    "[S93]"
```

See the [R demo](https://rextester.com/NEI84449) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FaQbdS/2).

**Pattern details**

- `(?:\G(?!^)(?:\([^()]*\))?\s*;\s*|\[)` - either the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!^)`) followed with any substring inside round parentheses (optional, see `(?:\([^()]*\))?`) and then a `;` enclosed with optional 0+ whitespaces (see `\s*;\s*`) or a `[` char
- `\K` - match reset operator discarding all text matched so far
- `[^][;()]+` - one or more chars other than `[`, `]`, `;`, `(` and `)`.

The `paste0("[", unlist(matches),"]")` part wraps the matches with square brackets.